# django registration : How to authenficate a user?

Tags: html, django, templates, registration

I'm using Django registration. I did all steps to include the application on my project.

After the user has logged successfully, I want to redirect him on an other page.
I did it, but the problem is that I wantt to check if a user is authenticated or not inside the template.

Because any user can access this page, typing it directly on the web browser.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a [look at the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

inside a view:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # User is logged in
```

inside a template:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    Only rendered for users that are logged in.
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent nonauthenticated user see the page, you can add a `@login_required` decorator to the view ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

So if the user isn't logged in, decorator redirects him to settings.LOGIN_URL